# Shutdown button only logs out ubuntu 15.04

Tags: shutdown, 15.04

Since i upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04, if i click on the shutdown button it only logs out and i have to click again on the shutdown button (from the ubuntu login screen) to power off the pc. How can i fix this?

Comment: Have the same problem on 16.04 LTS.

Comment: I have the same problem after I installed plank in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have docky installed this fixed the problem for both of my machines.

Ubuntu 15.04 Unity + Docky, Plank, or Cairo-Dock

(DOCKY)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano docky.desktop
add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

(IF YOU USE CAIRODOCK)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano cairo-dock.desktop
add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

Or you can just remove either one from autostart.

Example docky.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=docky
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Docky
Name=Docky
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
```

(IF YOU USE PLANK)

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano plank.desktop
add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

For example: cat ~/.config/autostart/plank.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/plank
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
Name=Plank
```

Note: Still happens on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: This seems a bit far fetched, considering that we don't know, if OP uses either of these.

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP.  I read Unity's shutdown/restart dialogue is not working when another application is registered to LauncherEntry interface of Unity DBus. -- This was for cairo-dock so I tried it with DOCKY on my 2 machines.  THIS DID fix the problem for me.  I'm only offering what worked for me.

Comment: Adding that I did a sudo apt-get install lightdm --reinstall and even a purge and reinstall, both failed to fix my problem.

Comment: In fact, i'm using Plank, a similar program. Is there a alternative?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot about adding plank to that list.  try editing Plank.desktop and adding the delay in it.  You can open startup applications and just disable it temporarily and reboot to test if plank is causing the problem.  Remember to REBOOT after making any changes.

Comment: Removing from startup applications solve the problem  but changing the file don't.
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=plank
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Plank Dock
Name=Plank Dock
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
X-GNOME-Autorstart-Delay=20

Comment: X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20 before the line
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true

Comment: Problem Solved!

Comment: Still happens on Ubuntu 15.10 with Plank, Docky, or Cairo-dock :P Workaround stills works: add X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20 to ~/.config/autostart/plank.desktop or whatever.

Comment: I wonder why is this actually happening? What's the problem behind all this?

Comment: I have used it with Plank and Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked perfect.

Comment: Not working for me. (Plank in Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less-command method for fix this issue.
1.First you have to install unity tweak tool.
2.Then open it and go to "Security" tab under "System" section

[image: unity tweak tool user interface]

3.You can see that "User log out" option is checked, Unckeck it.

[image: unity tweak tool Security tab]

4.Restart your PC.

Comment: It's really strange that if you mark to remove log out, it move the log out to shutdown and remove shutdown and reboot, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem caused when you add plank, docky or some other such docks to the startup spplications. This problem can easily be corrected by having a delay of a few seconds between the logging in and the starting of the application.

This delay can be added easily through the terminal. For example, for docky, you can use the commands:

```
cd ~/.config/autostart
nano docky.desktop
```

add

```
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=20
```

or you can just remove such a program from autostart.