# After installing plank shutdown logs me out

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, logout, plank

I know this is probably a duplicate, but the solution given in [Shutdown button only logs out ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621732/shutdown-button-only-logs-out-ubuntu-15-04) isn't working for me. So I am asking it again.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I did follow the steps given in above links. But the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the file `~/.config/autostart/plank.desktop`.
2. Add at the end of the file:

   ```
   X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=5
   ```