# Shutdown options not shown as expected

Tags: unity, 17.04, unity-control-center

When I press system cog and "Shutdown.." it just freezes some windows and shuts Ubuntu down. I would expect to see the options to Restart or Shutdown.

It happened after some work with terminal, probably some packages.

P.S. if it could be related I got this at the same time as this error [Missing System Settings after removing some packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453440/missing-system-settings-after-removing-some-packages) and non of the answers help

Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: *Ubuntu control center not working either*  makes it two questions in one question, please ask one question in one post :)

Comment: Funny thing it happened second time, and I had found the answer, but can't find it second time.. would appreciate if someone finds it and marks this as duplicate :D

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your desktop software got slightly messed up.  As a quick fix, this should work

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details of what you've been working with (version of Ubuntu, the meaning of "some work with terminal", etc), could you try restarting the window manager with following command

```
sudo systemctl restart lightdm
```

(Assuming you're running the latest version that uses systemd init instead of upstart)

Comment: I get this:
```$ Unknown operation lightdm.```

Comment: whoops, syntax error on my part. Answer edited.

Comment: Didn't help. But I found an answer someplace else. Should I answer my question or just delete it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621732/shutdown-button-only-logs-out-ubuntu-15-04 only in my case it was shutting down instead at first..

Comment: @Aurimas did the answer in that link worked for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked .. in addition to that I had something set in my `.profile`